# What is the difference between Anaconda Prompt and Anaconda Powershell Prompt?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, cmd, anaconda

I am learning Python using Anaconda. Earlier I had only **Anaconda Prompt**. But after recent update of Anaconda through

```
conda update conda
```

I came to see **Anaconda Powershell Prompt**. Few commands I tried in new **Powershell Prompt** which I used to do earlier in **Anaconda Prompt**. These commands worked fine.

Now, my question is what is the reason behind giving 2 command prompts by Anaconda? Is there any difference between their functionalities or capabilities?

My OS is Windows 7 and Conda version is 4.6.12.

Comment: this seems like a question that should be asked at the anaconda site - perhaps their forums?

Comment: I'm not an Anaconda employee, so this is only speculation, but Microsoft is trying to get rid of the legacy prompt (which the original Anaconda Prompt is based on) in favor of Powershell. If I recall correctly, the default terminal in Windows 10 is Powershell unless you specifically request otherwise. Hence, Anaconda need to switch.

Answer (score 12):

First, for everything from executing python related commands (`python`, `ipython`, `jupyter`, `conda`, etc.) to running Python scripts (e.g. `python helloworld.py`), there is **no difference**. So there is no worry ;)

And then, the only difference, as the name suggests, is the **windows shell environment** in which you running `conda` commands: `cmd.exe` (Command Prompt) vs `powershell.exe`.

---

Now let's talk a bit more about the difference: ([reference](https://superuser.com/a/570698/219121))

> Briefly, the [`cmd.exe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) is a simple shell introduced with Windows NT with the same basic syntax and functionality as DOS. It has relatively limited capabilities, especially when compared to *Unix/Linux shells*.
>
> And [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) is a modern shell implementation with all sorts of extra goodies (e.g. commands colorful highlight).

So, in **Anaconda Powershell Prompt**, you can run some powershell commands like these:

```bsh
> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.752
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.752
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

> $env:PATH
C:\Users\user-name\anaconda3;C:\Users\user-name\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;...
```

But in **Anaconda Prompt**, above commands would not be recognized, you can run this though:

```
>ver

Microsoft Windows [版本 10.0.18363.815]
```

---

And under the hood, **Anaconda Powershell Prompt** and **Anaconda Prompt** just two *shortcuts* invoking different commands:

```
%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command "& '%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate '%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3' "
```

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" %USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat %USERPROFILE%\anaconda3
```

[image]

Comment: should new packages for conda be installed with PowerShell Prompt or just Prompt?

Comment: @develarist Actually, it doesn't matter. These two are just different ways you run python/conda from command line. No matter which one you like to pick, all packages you installed would go to the same location, as long as you are in the same virtual environment.

Answer (score 2):

Windows offers two command line environments, the traditional "Prompt" ([`cmd.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd)) and the newer ["PowerShell"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/powershell). You can use Anaconda with either of these.

The documentation for [Windows commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) covers both.

Comment: Is it possible to use miniconda with powershell?

Comment: @softyodayoann Yes, Miniconda is the `conda` tool without the rest of the Anaconda distribution. That tool works the same way.

Comment: Thanks, I found a way using this command : ``` C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command & 'C:\\ProgramData\\miniconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\\ProgramData\\miniconda3' ``` !

Answer (score 2):

In order to understand the difference between **Anaconda Prompt** and **Anaconda Powershell Prompt**, you need to understand the difference between **Windows Command Prompt** and **Windows Powershell Prompt**.

[Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/) comes with a command-line shell a scripting language by Microsoft. You can use the scripting language to run commands like any other programming language as shown below,

```
PS C:\Users\coding_horse> $first="coding"
PS C:\Users\coding_horse> $second="horse"
PS C:\Users\coding_horse> $first+"-"+$second
coding-horse
```

Powershell also comes with additional benefits like **Aliases** which are very useful for people who come from a different platform. For example, on **Windows Command Prompt** you use `cls` to clear the contents, while on **Linux** you use `clear`. This forces you to learn terminal commands from scratch when you move from Linux to Windows or vise versa. Powershell Aliases solves this problem by creating aliases. Both `cls` and `clear` are aliases of `Clear-Host` and typing any of these three commands will clear the contents of the Powershell terminal. Similarly using `dir`, `ls` or `Get-ChildItem` will list the contents of the current folder. So, **Windows Powershell** allows you to use all of the **Windows Command Prompt** commands and gives you additional functionalities.

**Anaconda Prompt** is built on top of **Windows Command Prompt** and **Anaconda Powershell Prompt** is built on top of **Windows Powershell Prompt**. So, **Anaconda Prompt** supports all the commands of **Windows Command Prompt** and gives you additonal commands specific to anaconda like `conda -V` or `conda list` and so on. And **Anaconda Powershell Prompt** supports all of the **Windows Powershell Prompt** commands and additonal anaconda commands.

So, the take away is that if you use **Anaconda Powershell Prompt** you get all the functionalities of **Windows Command Prompt**, **Windows Powershell Prompt** and **Anaconda Prompt**.